# Android button background not loading when running the app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I had set background images of buttons(separate ) for four of them in my main menu having sizes of `640*150`, `320*75` and `160*38.5` in drawable hdpi, mdpi an ldpi folders respectively.

Earlier I had used a `100*100` as a background for all buttons and it worked properly.

The graphical layout shows the changes I have made but when I run the app in the emulator or the mobile i get a blank background.

Please help. I have tried reinstalling ,cleaning and running in debug but the problem exists.

Comment: dimension of your button?

Comment: hdpi having sizes ranging from 20 kb to 25 kb.N 640 BY 150 PIXELS.

Answer (score 0):

got it.. I had actually set a button_pressed.xml which changes button background n click which which changed it to the default background configuration